# Proving a function is bounded given that the function is uniform continuous over a bounded, closed domain

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let's say I have a function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is uniformly continuous, and $I$ is a colsed and bounded interval. Then $f(I)$ is closed by the following:

Assume $f(I)$ is not closed, and that its supremum is not in $\{f(I)\}$. The proof is similar for the assumption that the infimum is not in $\{f(I)\}$.

Then $\exists\ x_n \subseteq I$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x_0 \in I$,  but $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0) = \sup\{ f(I) \}$ that is not in $\{f(I)\}$

However because $I$ is closed and bounded, $x_0 \in I$

Therefore $f(x_0) \in  \{f(I)\}$

So $\sup\{f(x_n) \} \subseteq \{ f(I)\} $ which  contradicts the assumption

So $\{ f(I) \}$ is closed.

I'm just wondering whether this is proof has enough rigor, or whether I've missed something, as I feel my proofs need a little work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an entirely different approach than you took, but you could do something like the following:

If $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, is uniformly continuous on $I$, then the Extreme Value Theorem shows that $f$ attains its minimum and maximum values on $I$. It then directly follows that $f$ is bounded.

Note: If you want to get technical you could let $m_1,m_2$ be the minimum and maximum value respectively. Then let $M=max(|m_1|,|m_2|)+1$. Then conclude that $|f(x)|<M ~\forall x \in I$.